# Second Smallest Program input

Tags: c++

I've been having problems trying to fix a problem with my code when finding the second smallest of a random number of inputs.
Whenever i input two or more numbers of the same value after each and followed by different higher numbers (ex: 1 1 3 4) (ex: 3 3 3 4 5), i always get the error even though that's not what i want the program to do.
Any clues would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{  
    double smallest, second_Smallest,a;
    vector<double> v(0);

    cout << "Enter the numbers in random order: " << endl;
    try
    {
        while (cin >> a)
        {
            v.push_back(a);
        }

        if(v[0] < v[1])
        {
            smallest = v[0];
            second_Smallest = v[1];
        }
        else
        {
            smallest = v[1];
            second_Smallest = v[0];
        }

        for(int i = 2; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if (smallest > v[i])
            {
                second_Smallest = smallest;
                smallest = v[i];
            }
            else if (v[i] < second_Smallest)
            {
                second_Smallest = v[i];
            }
        }

        if (smallest == second_Smallest)
        {
            throw runtime_error("no second smallest");
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "The second smallest number is " << second_Smallest << endl;
        }
    }

    catch (runtime_error)
    {
        cout << "error: no second smallest " << endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Store the input into a set.  The second element will be the second smallest.

Comment: don't suggest set for such trivial problems. It will unnecessary make processing slower.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code set smallest and second smallest to same value and never reset it if the first 2 numbers are equal and all other are higher. Actually you don't need two special if conditions.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{  
    double smallest = 0xffff, second_Smallest=0xffff ,a;
    vector<double> v(0);

    cout << "Enter the numbers in random order: " << endl;
    try
    {
        while (cin >> a)
        {
            v.push_back(a);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if (smallest > v[i])
            {
                second_Smallest = smallest;
                smallest = v[i];
            }
            else if (v[i] < second_Smallest)
            {
                second_Smallest = v[i];
            }
        }

        if (0xffff == second_Smallest)
        {
            throw runtime_error("no second smallest");
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "The second smallest number is " << second_Smallest << endl;
        }
    }

    catch (runtime_error)
    {
        cout << "error: no second smallest " << endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```